# How to pass class name as parameter to a function in android?

Tags: java, android

In my android application, I have two classes, say X and Y.I have another class Z and inside that class I have a static function 'print'.This function should be called from both classes, X and Y and I want to pass class name of X and Y as parameters to the function 'print' when I call print function from both classes.What I have tried is,

```
public class X
 {
  public static String os="Android";
  String classname="X";
  Z.print(classname);
 }

public class Y
  {
   public static String os="IOS";
   String classname="Y";
   Z.print(classname);
  }

public class Z
  {

     public static void print(String classname)

      {

       System.out.println(classname.os);

      }
  }
```

But eclipse throws an error "os cannot be resolved or is not a field".I know the method I have used for passing class name is wrong.Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?...Thanks in advance....

Comment: Please your entire code, your code does not compile

Comment: @zaske, I think the compile error is the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can call getName method of class.

```
YourClass.class.getName();
```

In your case when you call print method of Z class, call like this:

```
Z.print(Y.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `print` method, the `classname` argument is an ordinary Java string.  It doesn't have a field called `os`.

If you want to pass both the class name and OS name to the `print` method,  you'll need to make `print` take two string arguments:

```
public static void print(String classname, String os)
{
  System.out.println(classname + ", " + os);
}
```

and pass both values when calling the it:

```
Z.print(classname, os);
```

Your other error is that your `X` and `Y` classes have code outside a method, which isn't allowed.

Comment: I have tried this method...But still eclipse cant detect the string 'os'

Comment: Then you need to post the modified code and the error message that you get.  The code you've posted already has multiple syntax errors, and you need to fix all of them before the compiler will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly pass os as the parameter?

```
class X
 {
  public static String os="Android";
  String classname="X";
  void print()
  {
    Z.print(os);
}
}

class Y
  {
   public static String os="IOS";
   String classname="Y";
   void print()
{
    Z.print(os);
}
}

class Z
  {

 public static void print(String x)

  {

   System.out.println(x);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Z.print()` to a method body.